# Tidy callbacks node.js

Tags: node.js, callback, express, redis

Trying to think of a logical way of structuring this. For simplicity, I am creating a user registration page utilising Node.js, Redis and Express.js.

User posts details to page.

Username is confirmed to be valid then Redis checks username is unique. If it is, we continue, if it isn't we return an error message and all the previous details.

Password is confirmed to be valid. If it isn't an error is returned and we don't continue.

Email is confirmed to be unique with Redis. If it is we continue, if it isn't we return an error message and stop.

If no errors at this point, the data is inserted into Redis.

This seems very simple, but using callbacks has generated a total mess - particularly when it comings to returning an error.

How can I structure this in a tidy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've experienced is callback hell. There are a variety of things you could do like name your callback functions instead of inlining them, follow the same pattern etc...

However, I would recommend you have a look at [the async module](https://github.com/caolan/async).

In your, very typical, case I would use async.series like this:

```
var validateUserName = function(username, callback){
  if(username!='valid'){
    return callback('invalid username');
  }
};
var checkRedis = function(username, callback){
  // check to redis
};
var checkPassword = function(password, callback){
  // if password valid callback();
  // else callback('invalid password');
}
etc...

async.series([checkUserName, checkRedis, checkPassword, etc...], next);
```